# Error when passing parameters to SSRS in an iframe via POST

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, reporting-services

I'm trying to create a simple proof-of-concept app that uses a custom interface for parameter selection, and then pass those parameters to an SSRS report hosted on SharePoint 2010. I want the report to be on the same page, so I've got it inside an `<IFRAME>`. For this POC, all I'm doing is collecting an item UPC via a simple text field - eventually I'll use some JavaScript code to some some fancier things like validation, but for now I just wanted to get the parameter passing to work. (I know I could do this by writing it as a .NET app and using a report viewer control, but I was hoping to avoid any managed code if possible to keep things simpler.)

If I dynamically build a URL with the UPC parameter in the query string and set the `<IFRAME>`'s `src` attribute, everything works fine. But, I'd prefer to use a POST so I can avoid any issues with the URL becoming too long. Based on [this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896362/ssrs-reportviewer-2010-iframe-ie-problem), here's my code:

```
function generateReport() {
    var frame = $("#report-viewer"),
        URL = $("#URL-field").val();

    var form = $('<form method="post" target="report-viewer" action="http://pigcentral/_vti_bin/reportserver?http://[link to report .rdl]"></form>');
    form.append('<input type="hidden" name="rs:Command" value="Render" />');
    form.append('<input type="hidden" name="rc:LinkTarget" value="main" />');
    form.append('<input type="hidden" name="rs:Format" value="HTML4.0" />');
    form.append('<input type="hidden" name="rs:Parameters" value="false" />');

    var URLField = $('<input type="hidden" name="URL" />');
    URLField.val(URL);

    form.append(URLField);

    $("#hidden-form").append(form);
    form.submit();
    $("#hidden-form").empty();
    frame.show();
}
```

When I trigger the POST, the report viewer displays in the `<IFRAME>`, but there's an error message:

> > Error: For more information about this error navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable remote errors.

I [turned on remote errors](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337165.aspx) for the site the report is hosted on (which also happens to be the site I've got this page hosted on) but didn't get any further information.

Anyone have any ideas why this isn't working, or at least where I could go to get more information about the error? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That is pretty cool, never thought about doing it that way.  Never tried it with javascript to html but I do know I had an example in a book I did that used a 'select' element inside the form with 'option' elements inside it.  There may be an issue with HTML structure.  Can you create the HTML manually first and try it before doing the javascript and assure it works as designed?

I do know in the lab I tried and it did work to change values.  I would assume you could generate the html with the javascript and do it but I am not certain.  I obtained this from the book "Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Reporting Services" by Brian Larson, abridged:

```
< form id="frmRender" action=" (link to report location on reportservice)" method="post" target="self">
< select ID="rs:Format" Name="rs:Format" size=1>
 < option value="HTML4.0">HTML 4</option>
< option value="Image">TIff Image</option>
< /select>
< /form>
```